# Carrierwave + S3: how to specify https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

How do I get my Rails + Carrierwave + S3 to serve images over https?

Right now the images come from:

http://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/f5314e1c866911e181b812314804a181_7.jpg

I want it to come from:

https://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com/f5314e1c866911e181b812314804a181_7.jpg

## Edit

Turns out the images are served from any number of hosts:

`distilleryimage11.s3`, `distillery.s3`, etc...

Is there a way to just set the protocol?

Here's my initializer:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => CONFIG['s3-key'],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => CONFIG['s3-secret'],
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'my_dir'
  # config.fog_host       = 'https://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com' # optional, defaults to nil
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a note that with Carrierwave 0.7 it's config.asset_host

If you use .fog_host you will get:

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method`fog_host=' for CarrierWave::Uploader::Base:Class (NoMethodError)

as explained in [undefined method `fog_host='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041498/undefined-method-fog-host)

HTH future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Fog with CarrierWave, [the documentation in the readme](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) says you can set the `fog_host` option:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy',       # required
    :region                 => 'eu-west-1'  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'name_of_directory'                     # required
  config.fog_host       = 'https://assets.example.com'            # optional, defaults to nil
  config.fog_public     = false                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

In your case, use `config.fog_host = https://distilleryimage1.s3.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: This worked at first, but now my images are being served from any number of hosts (distilleryimage5.s3, distillery.s3, etc...). Is there a way to just set the protocol? Couldn't find it in the code: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb

Comment: Ah, I see. It's interesting; according to https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb#L269-294, if `fog_host` is not set, it looks like it should use SSL by default...